# Sort folder paths using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm migrating files from a network drive to SharePoint. The migration tool generates report for each file and folder that is migrated in a csv format. The entries are in random order. I would like to generate a csv extract of all the folders from the report and sort them by the path.

for e.g. (folder names just for illustration)

```
https://mytenant/site/library/folder1
https://mytenant/site/library/folder1/folder12
https://mytenant/site/library/folder1/folder12/folder13
https://mytenant/site/library/folder2
https://mytenant/site/library/folder2/folder22
https://mytenant/site/library/folder2/folder22/folder23
```

Is that possible using powershell?

When these files are migrated to SharePoint, some of these files don't open in explorer view in IE11 due to the windows limitation of 256 characters.
I want to identify such folders that cause this issue and work out which folders with long names on renaming can significantly reduce this issue.

Comment: Yes that should be possible using Powershell. Why don't you update your question to show the format of the file you're reading as input, the file you'd like to generate as output and your attempt so far?

Comment: Thanks Paul.The input file is a csv format with columns- Path,Type,Filesize etc. The Type can be File or Folder. Path can be absolute path to Folder or File.There are thousands of records in csv. I've written a script to filter all folder paths that exceed 256 and output such paths. However this report doesn't help much as it doesn't identify which are the individual folders that if shortened can make the whole file path under 256. The folders are deep nested and that adds to the complexity.What I would like to see in the output is list of folders if shortened can fix 'x' no. of files

Comment: It's even less clear to me now what you would like in the output file. You can (and should) *edit your question* with all of this information. Show us an example with a few lines of example csv text of exactly what is in your input file, and then show what those same lines should look like in the output file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question and your comment correctly, this might help:

```
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\FilesAndFolders.csv' | 
            Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'Folder'} | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | 
            Sort-Object | 
            ForEach-Object {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'Path' = $_
                    'Length' = $_.Length
            }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\PathLengths.csv' -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

It reads the report CSV, gets only objects that are of type 'Folder' and sorts the resulting string array of path names. As output, it adds a `Length` property to every folder path.

Using your example the output onscreen is:

> ```
> Path                                                    Length
> ----                                                    ------
> https://mytenant/site/library/folder1                       37
> https://mytenant/site/library/folder1/folder12              46
> https://mytenant/site/library/folder1/folder12/folder13     55
> https://mytenant/site/library/folder2                       37
> https://mytenant/site/library/folder2/folder22              46
> https://mytenant/site/library/folder2/folder22/folder23     55
> ```

Comment: Thanks Theo. Now I need to work on the second part of the issue to identify such folders with long names if renamed can significantly reduce the issue when working with file explorer.